# Unir dados de duas planilhas no Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, planilha

Tenho duas planilhas no Excel.

Na primeira tenho os seguintes dados, por exemplo:

```
ID   | NOME
-----|----------
100  | Luiz
101  | Pedro
102  | Aline
```

Na segunda planilha, tenho:

```
ID   | CATEGORIA
-----|------------
100  | Livros
100  | Filmes
101  | Livros
101  | Games
101  | Móveis
102  | Filmes
```

Ou seja, nessa segunda planilha tem IDs que se repetem para cada categoria. Gostaria de unir essas duas planilhas, para que ficasse mais ou menos assim:

```
ID   | NOME      | CATEGORIA
-----|-----------|-------------
100  | Luiz      | Livros
100  | Luiz      | Filmes
101  | Pedro     | Livros
101  | Pedro     | Games
101  | Pedro     | Móveis
102  | Aline     | Filmes
```

Existe essa possibilidade?
Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Existe essa possibilidade?

Sim.

---

### PROCV

Na segunda planilha inclua a coluna desejada (`NOME`) e faça o `procv`:

```
=PROCV(A2;Planilha1.A:B;2;0)
```

Sendo:

- `A2` - a célula que contém o ID
- `Planilha1` - a planilha que contém os nomes
- `A:B` - seleção da coluna `A` e `B` da planilha `Planilha1`
- `2` - index da coluna com o valor que você quer trazer (coluna `NOME`)
- `0` - informa que você quer que o Excel procure pelo ID exato

---

### Veja também

Para mais informações, exemplos e vídeo explciativo, acesse a [página do Office](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/PROCV-Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-PROCV-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1).

---

Obs: Testei esse comando com LibreOffice. Com o Excel pode ter alguma sutil variação, mas o princípio é o mesmo.

Comment: Vou testar aqui. No caso, as duas planilhas tem que estar no mesmo arquivo e em abas separadas ou pode ser em arquivos separados?

Comment: Podem ser em arquivos separados. Não tem problema. Dá até pra fazer na mesma planilha, mas fica muito bagunçado. Faça em planilhas separadas mesmo

Comment: Á propósito, essa formula preenche apenas **uma** célula. Depois que digitar a formula tecle aperte o enter, depois clique novamente nessa célula e vai aparecer um pequeno quadrado preto no canto inferior direito da célula. Clique, segure e arraste para baixo para preencher as demais células.

Comment: As células estão ficando com "#NAME?".

Comment: LibreOffice mesmo.

Comment: Manda um print das suas planilhas, por favor